# How to pass Sys.argv[n] to a function from inside if "__name__" == "__main__"

Tags: python, arguments, with-statement, sys

Hi guys I'm trying to write a code that scrapes websites and get the links from the websites.
Now I'm trying to implement that a user will give the script a `link_list.txt` that the script will iterate over.

However, I'm not successful with my Sys.argv[]

Here is some of the code:

```
    def link_list_maker(self, link_list_path):
    self.link_list_path = link_list_path
    with open(link_list_path, 'r') as list:
        line = list.readline()
        print(line)  # expecting a line read


if __name__ == "__main__":
    CrawlerClass.link_list_maker(sys.argv[1])
    crawler = CrawlerClass("http://quotes.toscrape.com/")  # TODO: Make a sysargv to work wth link list from user
    crawler.start()
```

As you can see, I'm trying to give the `CrawlerClass.link_list_maker()` function a sys.argv, but all I get is: TypeError: `link_list_maker() missing 1 required positional argument: 'link_list_path'`

i run the script with: `python3 <script_name> <sys.argv[1]>`

How do I pass the argv[1] correctly to the function?

Comment: btw don't use `list` as a variable name. It is a built-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    crawler = CrawlerClass("http://quotes.toscrape.com/")  # TODO: Make a sysargv to work wth link list from user
    crawler.link_list_maker(sys.argv[1])
    crawler.start()
```

Comment: this made it work. Do you know a way that I can replace the http://quotes.toscrape.com/ and make it iterate over the list I made?

Comment: I don’t, sorry. But it does sound like a new question that you should post.